# Get data ready(one sample per row) for clustering using k-means?

Tags: opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means, sift

I'm trying to cluster keypoints (detected using SIFT) using the kmeans function, but I'm having trouble getting it ready for being used.

The keypoints are saved to an xml/yml file using the code below:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
Mat img;

img = imread("c:\\box.png", 0);

SiftFeatureDetector detector;
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector.detect(img, keypoints);



FileStorage fs("keypoint1.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
write(fs, "keypoints1", keypoints);
fs.release();
```

The xml saves the keypoints separated by spaces, and the yml separates the keypoints using commas.

```
%YAML:1.0
keypoints1: [ 6.1368021965026855e+000, 5.2649226188659668e+000,
    4.0740542411804199e+000, 2.7943280029296875e+002, 0., 9109760, -1,
    6.1368021965026855e+000, 5.2649226188659668e+000,
    4.0740542411804199e+000, 3.4678604125976562e+002, 0., 9109760, -1,
    1.5903041076660156e+002, 2.4698186874389648e+001,
    4.1325736045837402e+000, 9.7977493286132813e+001, 0., 10158336, -1,
    1.6808378601074219e+002, 2.5029441833496094e+001,
    4.2399377822875977e+000, 9.7380126953125000e+001, 0., 11993344, -1,
    1.9952423095703125e+002, 4.4663669586181641e+001,
    5.0049328804016113e+000, 5.7439949035644531e+001, 0., 7275008, -1,
    3.0947158813476563e+002, 4.6865818023681641e+001,......................
```

The [kmeans](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/clustering.html#double%20kmeans%28InputArray%20data,%20int%20K,%20InputOutputArray%20bestLabels,%20TermCriteria%20criteria,%20int%20attempts,%20int%20flags,%20OutputArray%20centers%29) function requires the input as one row per sample. Can some one please explain this, I mean can the above file be used as a single row? will it qualify for kmeans using FileStorage read method?

The reason I want to added to and read from a file is that suppose if I have 100 images whose keypoints need to be clustered. I want to append all those files into one huge file and cluster that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIFT features are one thing and the values for each feature build the vector. When you extract a SIFT descriptor from a SIFT keypoint you are extracting the magnitudes of the gradients in 8 possible orientations in a 4x4 region. You thus have a vector for each keypoint with 128 features, or if you want, 128 dimensions. It's the same as representing a point in the Euclidean space, but instead of having three dimensions you have 128. There is a variant of the regular SIFT descriptor that performs better. The Dense SIFT. Instead of calculating the keypoints from the Difference of Gaussians it places a rectangular grid on top of the image to extract the descriptors. Look for vl_feat in google.

Answer (score 2):

Tom is correct. Usually with SIFT, you use **more than one keypoint per image**. That is the whole idea behind keypoint detection, that you try to process only the "interesting" parts of the image in the further steps.

So for clustering images, regular SIFT features will not work too well. They are good for **panorama construction** and such things, where you expect to find the *same* keypoints across multiple images.

However, you can "abuse" SIFT keypoints; and that probably is what you are trying to reproduce. It would certainly help if you read the relevant articles, instead of just trying to figure it out yourself from a coding point of view.

A simple introduction can be found here:
  http://image-net.org/download-features

Notice how they sample the same number of keypoints from each image, by using a regular grid. Yet, they still do not put them together into one huge array - that doesn't work for similarity search. Instead they perform a kind of dimensionality reduction.

They run k-means on all of the *individual* keypoints of *all* images, to obtain 1000 "common" keypoints, called **visual words**. Then they translate each keypoint into the best matching visual word, and this way obtain a text-like representation of the image. Except that the keypoints don't have human-readable names, you can imagine representing the images as something like "sky sky sky sky fur fur fur forest sky fur sky fur water forest water water water forest" for an image with a beaver swimming in a lake.

On these **bag of words** representations you could then run clustering or similarity search again. K-means won't work well, because the vectors are sparse. Euclidean distance doesn't work well for sparse data, and k-means is unfortunately designed for Euclidean distance. Plus, the means are no longer sparse, and that makes them abnormal. Most likely, the resulting means will be more similar to each other than to the instances, taking the whole partitioning ad absurdum.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I will definitely look into your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The number of sift points vary with image, so there is no fixed length vector to project too. Furthermore, the ordering you concatenate them to create 1 big vector means the ordering is important. SIFT features are a *set* of points (not a vector)

You need a more sophisticated metric to define similarity. Euclidean or other vector based metrics won't work. OpenCV's K-means requires vector inputs so it won't work.

Comment: what I understood from your answer is that every image has a different amount of detected keypoints and the order of keypoints is important and this cannot be concatenated into one big vector. I am not bothered by that. I just want the vector of keypoints for each image to be saved in a single row, and the keypoints for the second image to be saved in the next row; as this is the format required for kmeans.

Comment: what do you mean that SIFT features are a set of points and not a vector?

Comment: I never said that. if i did it must have been a typo. Since I know that the SIFT keypoints are stored in a vector

Comment: And I get it now, I was confused about what he was saying